# Apply MySQL COUNT() in php Query w/ Selected Column Names

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am trying to apply COUNT() in a query and I have it working like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, Title, images, recdate, 'item' AS type FROM ads_list WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14)";
```

**I've tried:**

```
1. $sql = "SELECT id, Title, images, recdate, 'item' AS type COUNT(*) FROM ads_list WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14)";

2. $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) id, Title, images, recdate, 'item' AS type FROM ads_list WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14)";

3. $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id), Title, images, recdate, 'item' AS type FROM ads_list WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14)";

4. $sql = "SELECT id, Title, images, recdate, 'item' AS type FROM ads_list WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14) COUNT(*)";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to supply a `GROUP BY` statement as well if you use `COUNT`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: But this works perfectly fine: $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ads_list WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14)"; No GROUP BY().

Comment: I am creating a custom pagination script.

Comment: So you want to count the rows within each 14 day period?

Comment: I'm counting the total rows returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count(*) is a group by function, it returns the count of rows selected. You must have a group by function on any columns which are not included in the group by clause. So, you can do:

```
SELECT count(*) as 'Count' FROM ads_list WHERE ...
```

but you can't (directly) select one group by function and four standard columns. What are you trying to achieve with the count(*)?

For total rows, you can use `mysql_num_rows($result_resource)`. If you need the rows and the count (and you are using standard mysql library) that is probably the best way to get what you want. If you don't need the rows (only the count) then use count(*).